# $stateChangeSuccess event firing twice

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui.router for routing implementation for angularjs SPA application and have the below code in navbar.html page

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a ui-sref="about" ng-click="$root.sideMenuOpen = false"  ng-bind="languageData['About']"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**router.js**

```
.state('about', {
                url: '/about/:jump',
                views: {
                    'mainView': {
                        templateUrl: '/modules/about/about.html',
                        controller:'AboutCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            // Code details
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

**app.js**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {

// Code details
  console.log('Testing')
});
```

The above app.js file is referenced in the index.html page. Now when I navigate to the About link present in the navbar.html I see in the console window the console.log value with 'Testing' gets printed twice.

Can anyone provide their guidance to fix this issue.

Comment: It prints for the first time when you load the app as state changing getting succeeded when your home page opened. Then when you moving to about, it's getting printed again. After opening the app clear the console. I think you don't find your problem

Answer (score 0):

try binding the event to the specific `$scope` instead of the `$rootScope`, this should prevent the event to trigger before the component is bootstrapped

Perhaps the event is firing multiple times because you have a route that redirect to another one and the `$rootScope` is notified twice.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {

// Code details
  console.log('Testing')
});
```